# How do I download a specific version of a module?

Tags: console

The official documentation for Drupal Console says that the arguments for [`drupal module:download`](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/module-download.html) are the following.

```
drupal module:download [arguments] [options]
```

is there an argument or option to specify the dev/beta version of the module?

Answer (score 0):

We can use following code to download latest stable release :

```
drupal mod modulename --latest
```

if we want to select a specific release other than latest then we can go for

```
drupal mod modulename --unstable
```

hope this will help.
https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/module-download.html